# Intercept iOS Device internet traffic with profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to create an a parental-control app very similar to [Onavo](http://www.onavo.com/), other than I'm not compressing any data, I'm just storing the URL being requested and letting it go on its way.

Basically, I just want to install a profile that will tell my app anytime an internet request is made on the device (assuming my app is running in the background). This is an even simpler version than what [Onavo](http://www.onavo.com/) does (intercept internet actions and reroutes them), so I know it's possible I just can't seem to find any documentation for it...

Can anyone point me in the right direciton? Google is failing me.

I'm an intermediate iOS developer. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do this easily on iOS. Applications are sandboxed and are not able to intercept any information or system calls from other applications. Onavo works simply by setting up a proxy on your device that reroutes all traffic to their own servers (hosted on EC2) that compress the data there.

Comment: Wait, then how does Onavo track which apps are using the data?

Comment: @TommyCrush: Have you figured out how Onavo doing that?

Comment: BTW. I just looked at Onavo. It's doing it on the server side. It just install VPN configuration profile and later a user has to connect through this VPN. So, it can compress, count data usage and so on on the server side and send it to Onavo iOS application.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @VictorRonin!